# Slick.js not initilizing properly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slick.js

I´m trying to reproduce an issue that I have with Slick.js in my AngularJs webapp in a plunker. Slick.js is working in my website, but not working in the plunker. I don´t know what am I missing.

Please see the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/35Sj5O?p=preview

This is the main code in the controller:

```
<div class="slick-container" slick>
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="photo in boat.photos" is-loaded>
                <img ng-src="{{photo.url}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Directives:

```
.directive('slick', function() {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {              
    $(document).ready(function () {
     console.log("Slick called");
     scope.$on('content-changed', function() {
      console.log("Slick initialized");
      $(".slick-container").not('.slick-initialized').slick(
        {adaptativeHeight: true,
         dots: true,
         lazyLoad: 'ondemand'});
      });               
    });
  };

  return {        
      link: link        
  };
})


.directive('isLoaded', function () {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) {
            scope.$emit('content-changed');
            console.log('page Is Ready!');
          }
        }
   };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your directive.js file with the below code

```
'use strict';

/* Directives */


angular.module('myApp.directives', [])  

.directive('isLoaded', function () {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) {
            scope.$watch('content-changed', function (){
              $(".slick-container").not('.slick-initialized').slick(
                {adaptativeHeight: true,
                dots: true,
                lazyLoad: 'ondemand'});
             })
            console.log('page Is Ready!');
          }
        }
   };
});
```

Comment: For development purposes it´s ok, but for performance purposes I would like to avoid to have a lot of "$watch" in production. Is it possible to make it work without the watches? Why is it working in my development environment and not in the plunker?